# returning all indexes of an array that have a key that matches a search criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got an array of objects and I need to get their positions in the array where the key ecommerce_order_number value matches the number im searching for.

Ive tried doing a for loop, but I can see that this isnt a good idea as there may be 500 + checks im doing against an array of order numbers i have that is seperate.

Usually I would just loop through and get all the matches and continue to get out of there. but Im hoping there is a cleaner approach using vanilla javascript.

```
var myTransactions = [];
myTransactions[0].order = 'S17243';


for(i=0; i < myTransactions.length; i++)
{
// 
}
```

but I can see my looping would be limited to the number of transaction count, and if there are more payments compared to the number of transactions which does happen, i wont be able to obtain all the indexes of the payments array that match.

Is there a function that will search an array of object and return the indexes of all keys found to match a particular string ?

```
var payments=    [{
        "id": "11419",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Angela smith",
                "id": "6641"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3810.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17247",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11420",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Paul Georgeson",
                "id": "6640"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3539,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17223",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11421",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Leanne Smithy",
                "id": "6638"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "336"
            },
            "amount": 1617.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }];
```

Comment: var ids=array.reduce((arr,el,i)=>(el.sth===true&&arr.push(i))||arr,[])

Answer (score 0):

```
var payments=    [{
    "id": "11419",
    "recordtype": "payment",
    "cols": {
        "entity": {
            "name": "Angela smith",
            "id": "6641"
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "test-data",
            "id": "335"
        },
        "amount": 3810.2,
        "ecommerce_order_number": "S17247",
        "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
    }
}, {
    "id": "11420",
    "recordtype": "payment",
    "cols": {
        "entity": {
            "name": "Paul Georgeson",
            "id": "6640"
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "test-data",
            "id": "335"
        },
        "amount": 3539,
        "ecommerce_order_number": "S17223",
        "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
    }
}, {
    "id": "11421",
    "recordtype": "payment",
    "cols": {
        "entity": {
            "name": "Leanne Smithy",
            "id": "6638"
        },
        "account": {
            "name": "test-data",
            "id": "336"
        },
        "amount": 1617.2,
        "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
        "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
    }
}];


var ids=payments.reduce((arr,el,i)=>(el.cols&&el.cols.ecommerce_order_number.includes("S17243")&&!arr.push(i))||a‌​rr,[]);
```

You could use the Array.prototype.reduce method...

Longform:

```
var ids=payments.reduce((arr,el,i)=>{
 if(el.cols&&el.cols.ecommerce_order_number.includes("S17243")) arr.push(i);
return arr;
},[]);
```

http://jsbin.com/jucexilude/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and i did it using `Array.map`.

```
var payments=    [{
        "id": "11419",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Angela smith",
                "id": "6641"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3810.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17247",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11420",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Paul Georgeson",
                "id": "6640"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3539,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17223",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11421",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Leanne Smithy",
                "id": "6638"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "336"
            },
            "amount": 1617.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }];

var arrOfIndexes = payments.map((payment, index, completeArr) => {
                       if(payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === "S17243") {
                          return index;
                       } else { return null }
                   }).filter(Boolean); // filter used to remove falsey values
console.log(arrOfIndexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function in order to retrieves all the objects with a specific attribute value, then you could get only the id if you need, see following please:

**Get all the objects with ecommerce_order_number = "S17243":**

```
var filteredObj = $.grep(payments, function(obj) {
    return obj.cols.ecommerce_order_number === "S17243";
});
```

**Get only the ids of the above objects:**

```
var onlyIds = filteredObj.map(function(obj) {return obj.id;});
```

**Combine the above codes in one line instructions:**

```
var oneLineObj = $.grep(payments, function(obj) {
    return obj.cols.ecommerce_order_number === "S17243";
}).map(function(obj) {return obj.id;});
```

See following example please:

```js
var payments=    [{
        "id": "11419",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Angela smith",
                "id": "6641"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3810.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17247",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11420",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Paul Georgeson",
                "id": "6640"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3539,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17223",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11421",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Leanne Smithy",
                "id": "6638"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "336"
            },
            "amount": 1617.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "test",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Alessandro",
                "id": "1"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "336"
            },
            "amount": 5000.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
            "datecreated": "18/5/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }];


var filteredObj = $.grep(payments, function(obj) {
    return obj.cols.ecommerce_order_number === "S17243";
});

var onlyIds = filteredObj.map(function(obj) {return obj.id;});

console.log("IDS: ", onlyIds);
console.log("COMPLETE OBJECTS: ", filteredObj);

var oneLineObj = $.grep(payments, function(obj) {
    return obj.cols.ecommerce_order_number === "S17243";
}).map(function(obj) {return obj.id;});

console.log(oneLineObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure javascript, no jquery solution.**

You could use new array helpers: `.filter` or `.find`.

---

**.filter solution** if you expect to have more than one results.

```
const resultFiler = payments.filter(payment => {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).map(payment => payment.id);
```

`.filter` helper only returns complete array element. We could not do something like `return payment.id` which would be ideal in our case, because we only care about `.id` property.

To get `.id` poperty we used `.map(payment => payment.id);`.

---

**.find solution** if you expect only one result.

```
const resultFind = payments.find(payment => {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).id;
```

If you are not familiar with fat arrow/ES6 syntax here is equivalent code:

```
var resultFiler = payments.filter(function (payment) {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).map(function (payment) {
  return payment.id;
});

// Using find
var resultFind = payments.find(function (payment) {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).id;
```

See working example.

```js
var payments=    [{
        "id": "11419",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Angela smith",
                "id": "6641"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3810.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17247",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11420",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Paul Georgeson",
                "id": "6640"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "335"
            },
            "amount": 3539,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17223",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11421",
        "recordtype": "payment",
        "cols": {
            "entity": {
                "name": "Leanne Smithy",
                "id": "6638"
            },
            "account": {
                "name": "test-data",
                "id": "336"
            },
            "amount": 1617.2,
            "ecommerce_order_number": "S17243",
            "datecreated": "10/4/2017 5:42 PM"
        }
    }];
    
const searchValue = "S17243"
// Find all matching occurrences
    
const resultFiler = payments.filter(payment => {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).map(payment => payment.id);


// Using find
const resultFind = payments.find(payment => {
  if (payment.cols.ecommerce_order_number === searchValue) {
    return payment;
  }
}).id;

console.log(resultFiler);
console.log(resultFind);
```